# Is there a way to create a Task Manager Django App?

Tags: python, django

[image]

I wish to create a Task Manager Django app that can allow a user to sign in and new users to sign up. I've already done that part.

A signed-in user can create a 'Team' and can add other users to his team. Now I want a message to be sent to the added users, saying like : 'Hey, you have been added to the Team of xyz User'. How to intercommunicate ? Is there something like an FB friend request possible here ?

A signed-in user can create and assign a 'Task' to a single 'Team' but he may or may not assign it to the entire team, i.e. he can choose some members of a team and reject others, but all this must be from a single team. How to manage this ?

Another issue is that once the user has signed in, he can only view the teams that he has created and also those teams to which he has been added. He must not view 'all' the created teams.

I'm an infant to Django and I need to submit this project. Please help.
Thanks a lot !

I've done the sign-in and sign up part.

## models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.urls import reverse

class Team(models.Model):
    team_name=models.CharField(max_length=100 )
    team_members=models.ManyToManyField(User)


    class Meta:
        ordering=['team_name']


    def __str__(self):
        return self.team_name


class Task(models.Model):
    task_name=models.CharField(max_length=100, verbose_name='title')
    task_description=models.TextField(max_length=500, verbose_name='description')

    #task_creator=models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    team_assigned = models.ForeignKey(Team,
on_delete=models.CASCADE,verbose_name='Select Team')
    class Meta:
        ordering=['task_name']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.task_name
```

## forms.py

```
from django import forms
from .models import Task, Team
from django.contrib.auth.models import User 

class TaskForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model=Task
        fields=('task_name','task_description', 'team_assigned')

class TeamForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model=Team
        fields=('team_name','team_members',)
```